# Accessing clojurescript from html

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I'm using catnip/leiningen in an attempt to learn Clojure... So I have a simple website and now I'd like to add a clojure-script in my page.

So I took a simple example but now got stuck on how to access my script from my site.

My project.clj

```
(defproject hello-world "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.2"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.2"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              [{:source-path "src"
                :compiler
                {:output-to "resources/public/cljs/main.js"
                 :output-dir "resources/public/cljs"
                 :optimizations :simple
                 :pretty-print true}}]}
  :ring {:handler hello-world.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.3"]]}})
```

Relevant part of handler.clj

```
(defn header [title]
  (html 
   [:head
    [:title title]
    [:script "/cljs/play.js"]]))
```

If I run lein ring server there are nothing at `http://localhost:8080/resources/public/cljs/main.js`. How to map the requests for js so that my site can find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the [:script]-tag that needed to be rewritten to either:

```
[:script {:src "/cljs/main.js"}]
```

or

```
(include-js "/cljs/main.js")
```

to generate a corrent link to the javascript-file.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript file should be accessible under `http://localhost:8080/cljs/main.js` not `http://localhost:8080/resources/public/cljs/main.js`. Your actual code looks to be ok otherwise.

Did you run `lein cljsbuild once` and did it create a JavaScript file under `/resources/public/cljs/`?

Comment: The problem was in the [:script]-tag. I replaced with (include-js "/cljs/main.js") and it started to work. So my code wasn't ok...

Comment: @Roland True. You could have also used `[:script {:src "/cljs/main.js"}]`

Comment: @Roland thanks, but I think the correct procedure is for you to add an additional answer in which you explain how you solved your problem and then accept that as the correct answer.